# CakePHP - Layout folder for ajax-requests

Tags: php, ajax, json, cakephp

i will have two different request types for my application, AJAX and JSON.
AJAX shall output html-code; JSON shall return pure JSON Code.
I managed to send JSON Output by calling controller actions like this: **/index.json** --> Outputs **json code**, view lies under **/View/Test/json/index.ctp**

How do i manage to store the view files in **/View/Test/ajax/index.ctp** for a request like **/index.ajax**

I tried setting
    **Router::parseExtensions('json', 'ajax');**
in my /Config/routes.php but then callling index.ajax just outputed the standard /View/Test/index.ctp insetad of /View/Test/ajax/index.ctp

What am I doing wrong?

With kind regards,

Battlestr1k3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is a method, not a data type.

You may be making an ajax request which will return json in which case you can use it in a json view or decode it and use it in a standard view.

If you are retuning a json object or array via your ajax request to display as HTML you can also parse it with jquery. See here for more information:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Edit following comments:

First, you need to have a view file to output the HTML, this will be in:

app/View/Tests/index.ctp 
app/View/Tests/add.ctp

etc

You then have a corresponding method in your controller:

```
public function index(){
  //index method here
}
```

At this point your index view will render when you go to /tests/index.html in your browser, and all the HTML structure you have set in the index.ctp file will be showing. However you will have no data as you have not retrieved it from the database or set it for your view to use.

So, to render it you run your ajax call and set the url as /Tests/index

Then add the logic to your index function in your controller something like:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
  //debug can cause problems with AJAX requests so switch it off if it is on
  Configure::write('debug', 0);

//you need to pass the id through in the data parameter of your ajax call  
$id = $this->request->query['id'];

  $settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Test.id' => $id),
  ); 
  $data = $this->Test->find('first', $settings);

  return json_encode($data);
}
```

This will return a json array which you can parse with jquery and append to your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your fast anwer. I already thought about parsing JSON in Javascript, but with a HTML-table and many different tags it would be very time intensive to write a JSON-parser for it. I just want to use two folders, one for JSON Requests (already working) and one for HTML-AJAX Requests. What could I use instead of ajax, html is obviously not working.

Comment: Can I clarify, are you doing an AJAX request to get your data? For example are you trying to update the view without the user having to reload the page? If so you will have no choice but to use and therefore parse a JSON aray - this is how AJAX will return the variable. If you are not fetching the data with AJAX then you just need to set variables in your controller and use the standard cake views. You mention folders, in this case it would be /view/test/json/index.json and /view/test/index.ctp for the PHP/HTML view file.

Comment: Exactly! I currently output html by calling index.json, which is incorrect because it returns no json. So the best practice would be (for html loaded by ajax) to load a view in the default directory like /View/Test/ajax_tabledata.ctp? Could I set up something like a general routing, let's say all requests with the .ajax-externsion should receive output from /View/Test/ajax/action.ctp? I thought about calling the method beforeRender() in AppController.php

Comment: Answer edited, hopefully this will get you on the right path.